# Misleading React Native Sticky Headers on Android

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I'm interested in getting sticky headers to work on RN Android but they don't - and they do on iOS.

According to official documentation **https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html** they claim to support sticky headers throughout RN without being biased towards iOS.

Specifically

> renderSectionHeader function
>
> (sectionData, sectionID) => renderable
>
> If provided, a sticky header is rendered for this section. The sticky
>   behavior means that it will scroll with the content at the top of the
>   section until it reaches the top of the screen, at which point it will
>   stick to the top until it is pushed off the screen by the next section
>   header.

Do you see any words saying that it works only for iOS?

On Android, sticky headers don't work.

According to official bug reporting documentation  **https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2700** Facebook is advertising that they will not implementing sticky headers on Android "since we have no need for it internally."

Is there any point in even asking about why sticky headers don't work on Android? Will FB even consider doing anything about it? (seems like a no). Is there another way to get sticky headers to work on Android?

Thanks in advance,
Dritan

Comment: I'd love to get people's input why they're down voting my question. Nothing is out of the ordinary. I can only guess that people don't like it when the official documentation is questioned about its correctness. If you have a legitimate remark please leave a comment.... or don't if you want to be a part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

React Native for Android has been a mostly community-driven effort so far. Most features come from community contributors as pull requests which is the case here as well:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9456

The pull request has been merged so I would expect sticky headers for Android to appear in a future release.

Comment: It looks like this is available in v0.35: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.35.0-rc.0

Comment: Thanks for this David! I'll keep an eye out for RN latest release notes myself

Comment: The commit was reverted from a ScrollView not ListView. github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/…. Please note that according to RN documentation, sticky headers are supposed to work on a ListView facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html. Even the release notes mention that sticky headers for ScrollView will be available on 0.35.0 and they briefly were but were reverted. I'm trying to find a solution for a ListView so I can reap the benefits of recycling and preventing unnecessary rendering of children if not visible

Answer (score 1):

Sticky header for Android is assumed that it will be included in RN 0.44 release

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2700